# How to use robot_pose_ekf and other ROS Packages?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am super new to ROS. I have a decent amount of programming experience and have academic coursework under my belt in AI and robotics. I have also worked through the ROS tutorials. That being said, I have 0 real world experience with ROS.

I am working on a project where I need to use robot_pose_ekf and maybe amcl. I think I understand how to publish the messages they subscribe to, but I have no idea how to play around with the code for these packages, or how to get them on my computer, or how to actually use them with my robot, aside from what they publish and subscribe to.

Any kind of help on how to use these tools would be super appreciated. Thank you!!

(PS - I have the sensors needed for all of these things)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211602/how-to-use-robot_pose_ekf-and-other-ros-packages?/) by [SilvrCenturion](https://answers.ros.org/users/22840/silvrcenturion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-18**:
Perhaps not the answer you were looking for, but you'll do yourself a favour if you pick up some books for ROS if you're a beginner. See the [wiki/Books](http://wiki.ros.org/Books) page for that. "A Gentle Introduction to ROS" is free, so you can start with that. "ROS By Example" should help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can clone them from version control to your catkin workspace and build from source or install them (if you don't already have them) by running `sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-<package_name>`.  Tab complete helps with this, too.

Once you have them installed, look at some example code that might be found in their repositories or any tutorials on the ros wiki for them.  If it's just a think that subscribes to certain topics, make sure your newly installed or complied node is running via `rosrun` or a launch file you made, and the correct topics are being published!

---

Originally posted by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) with karma: 350 on 2015-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1